# Retrieve info from last record of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model Lead which has a has_many Relationship with Activity.

I want to display a list of all leads on the leads index page, including a count of all activities and the timestamp of the latest activity of each lead.

The model looks like this:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :activities, -> { order("activitytimestamp DESC") }, dependent: :destroy

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :lead
```

The view looks like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Activity | last</th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <% @leads.each do |lead| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= lead.activities.size %> | <%= lead.activities.last %></td>
       ...
     </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Obviously `lead.activities.last` doesn't work.

What do I need to do to display the timestamp of the latest `lead.activities` Record?

Comment: You should use [`includes` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: OK thanks, but how do I display the timestamp of the latest activity in the index view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close!

General configuration of a general attribute of the most recent record related to a specific record is:

```
specific_record.related_records.last.general_attribute
```

or, in your case, I believe:

```
lead.activities.last.timestamp_field
```

The issue with

```
leads.activities.last
```

is that it returns the object, not the information in the field of that object, which is what you're looking for.